# How to access a thread started initially when page is loaded, later in an ajax method call in c# mvc ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I am using C# 5.0, VS 2012, MVC4. I have a scenario where I need to cache employees data and query the cache when performing a search on employees info.

I am not displaying all employees initially but wanted to initiate a thread to cache all employees. So in index method when view is displayed, I am doing this

```
       //Starting a thread to load the cache if its null
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["AllEmployees"] == null)
        {
            thCacheAllEmployees = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CacheAllEmployees));
            thCacheAllEmployees.Name = "CacheAllEmployees";
            thCacheAllEmployees.Start();
        }
```

CacheAllEmployees is a separate method which will query LDAP and stores all employees in Cache. It will take about 15 secs for LDAP query. But within these first 15 secs after view is loaded and cache is not yet loaded, then when user starts typing in search box, I am making a ajax method call to GetFilteredEmployees action method. I want to access previously started thread, check if its alive, then to wait for that thread to complete so that I don't need to do a fresh LDAP query again.

```
      if (thCacheAllEmployees.IsAlive)
        {
            thCacheAllEmployees.Join();

            if (HttpRuntime.Cache["AllEmployees"] != null)
                return (List<CMSUser>)HttpRuntime.Cache["AllEmployees"];
        }
```

But the problem is, when its ajax call seems like it will be a new Main Thread and doesn't know about thCacheAllEmployees. So thCacheAllEmployees will be null object. So I need to get the instance of this thread from currently all active threads in application.

I can store thread id of thCacheAllEmployees when view is loaded first time in a session variable, but how can I access that thread from pool of threads when making ajax method call ?

Is there any better way of doing this ? please give ur suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you think threads think actions not data. When you want to store data you do not put that data on a thread, you put it into memory, then that memory is accessible by one ore more threads depending on the scope.

There are lots of ways you can store that data. I'm not sure if the data to cache is unique for different user sessions or if you want just one global cache. Anything that you want to access from anywhere you can put in a static variable. You just have to be sure to use locks so that multiple threads do not try to access that data at the same time which is never safe.

---

**Model**

```
public static class MyCache
{
     private static object LockToken = new object(); 
     private static List<CMSUser> _Users { get; set; }

     static MyCache()
     {
        _Users = GetUsers();
     }

     public static List<CMSUser> Users
     {
          lock (LockToken)
          {
               return _Users;
          }
     }
}
```

---

**Controller**

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public List<CMSUser> Get()
    {
        return MyCache.Users;
    }
}
```

---

**View**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(users) {
        // do something with users here
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I make ajax method call (main thread) to wait for the thCacheAllEmployees thread to complete and then query from filled in cache ? Yes its a global cache.

Comment: I am initiating a thread when the page is loaded first. And then when making ajax call, I need to check for if cache is filled or else I need to wait for that thread to complete. How can I do that ?

Comment: To outline the example I gave, you make an ajax call to an api controller. That controller will pull the users from a static variable. The first time this happens the variable is initialized, caching the users for all future requests. You do not need to do anything special for the ajax call to 'wait'. You just call the controller and when it returns it will run the success function (or error function if something went wrong). Eventually the ajax request would time out, but 15 seconds should be fine and you could always extend the timeout if you ran into that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why wait for the first call to cache data? You could do this during the application start by adding it to the `Application_Start` function in `Global.asax`.

This will mean you will have a 15 sec overhead when your application starts, but after that you are good to go.

If you do want to use a thread here too, you could put its id in a static variable, and use that to check if the list has loaded.

Comment: I can't put overhead while starting the application.